# C++ Age won't display (struct)

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, runtime-error

I have written a code using struct and pointers, the problem is that when you enter for age, the result would be zero 0. It would be helpful if you take a look at my code

```
Person's name: Billy
    Person's age: 25
    Write your hobby[0]:Kungfu 
    Write your hobby[1]:soccer
    write your hobby[2]:basketball
    Write your crush name: Jake
    Name:Billy
    Age:0
    Hobbies[0]:Kungfu
    Hobbies[1]:soccer
    Hobbies[2]:basketball
    Crush: Jake
```

For some reason Age is assign to 25 but in result it shows 0 why is it happening

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

//declare structure to store info about Billy
struct Son{
    string name;
    string crush;
    int age;
    string hobbies[3];
}Person;

int main(){
    string sAge;
    int i;
    Son* info = new Son;
    info = &Person;
    //user interface
    //Person's name
    cout << "Person's name: ";
    getline(cin, info ->name); //inputs person's name
    //Person's age
    cout << "Person's age: ";
     //inputs person's age
    getline(cin,sAge);
    (stringstream)sAge << info ->age; 
    //for loop to get hobbies
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << "Write your hobby[" << i <<"]: ";
        getline(cin,info ->hobbies[i]); //inputs the person hobby three times
    }
    //Person's crush
    cout << "Write your crush name: ";
    getline(cin, info ->crush); //inputs the person's crush *opitional*

    //output statement
    cout << "Name: " << info ->name << endl; //display name
    cout << "Age: " << info ->age << endl; //display age
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){ //display hobbies
    cout << "Hobbies[" << j << "]: " << info ->hobbies[j] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Crush: " << info ->crush << endl; //display crush                                             
    delete info;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Improve the code till you get no warnings. learn how to **use a debugger** like `gdb`

Comment: `Son* info = new Son; info = &Person;` Why is `info` dynamically alocated? and why are you setting it to the address of Person? That's a memory leak!

Comment: Well bro,                                                               1) I do not have a mac                                                  2) Beginner at c++, so don't really know                               @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: I don't have a mac neither (only a PC running Linux/Debian/Sid)

Comment: @Jim what do you need mac for? Just install some debugger like `GDB` or `CDB` if Visual Studio.  GDB works on every single platform.

Comment: debug is the most basic thing programmers must do. If you don't like commands then use and IDE such as VS

Comment: That is the software I use to program c++ @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Comment: then why don't try debugging and find out what's the problem with your code

Answer (score 3):

`(stringstream)sAge << info ->age;`

This is not the correct way of doing it, you can use either one of those:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << sAge;
ss >> info->age;
```

`info->age = atoi(sAge.c_str());`

Alternatively, you can use `std::atoi(sAge)` which accepts `std::string` right away, however, since you have `using namespace std;` it should use it automatically.  Thanks to @alexolut for stating this.

You're basically casting `string` to `stringstream` which is a huge failure, `stringstream` isn't a subclass of `string`.  Also you shouldn't use C-style casts in C++ at all, learn to use `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` to generate better warnings (Thanks to @JohnZwinck for stating this).

Side note: you're including `Windows.h` and you're not using any of it's functions.

Comment: And in general, you should not use C-style casts in C++, ever.  There is always a safer one available: const_cast, static_cast, dynamic_cast, or reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @Jim You should really read a C++ standard book to understand all of the C++ STD library has to offer.  Or check some documentations.  Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: Instead of atoi() you can use std::stoi() which accept std::string argument (no need to get c-string via c_str() method). This could be more C++ way.